# Where is the date and time stored in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I need to access the date and time in ubuntu from a program.This program may not use any commands to do this. So making a call to date is not an option. 
Is there a file or files which hold this information? 
Where can it be found ?

Comment: may not use any commands in a program? are you using `bash`? or what programming language to do this?

Comment: I'm doing it in Python , but I would not like code as an answer. I think it should be held somewhere on the system , in a file I could parse? If not the only option I can think of is a request to a time server ?

Comment: It's stored inside of the operating system.

Comment: Melpomene could you elaborate please?

Comment: What do you mean by "may not use any commands"? Are Python modules like `time` off-limits?

Comment: @YarpoleCosgrave No.

Comment: By commands I mean built-in ubuntu/Linux features.I don't there there is anything in the requirements excluding python modules. Thanks I don't know how I did not see this

Comment: "By commands I mean built-in ubuntu/Linux features." That's not what "commands" means. The `time()` system call is a built-in Linux feature. I think you mean *external* commands, running a program.

Comment: If you want to get the time without invoking an external command, you need to use language features. The solution is specific to the language you're using. You say in comments you're using Python; you should mention that and add a "python" tag. If you don't want code as the answer, you're probably in the wrong place; this is a programming site.

Comment: It is possible to point some one in the right direction without giving them a fully implemented solution , allowing the person asking the question to get some kind of learning experience.As has been done in the accepted answer.You are correct this is a programming site where people who encounter an issue can ask for help. That is inherently different from a do my homework for me site. I will however add python to the tag as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). There are some [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...) to query the time (since [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)); in particular [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) and [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html).

You then need to convert that time into a string, probably using [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) then [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html). That conversion use some files notably `/etc/timezone` (and some under `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` ...) according to `TZ` variable (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html)).

BTW, `date`  is free software (so you could study its source code). And you could [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) it.

See also [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399616/50557).